# size of basic data types in C

Tags: c, types

I have a sample program that I copied from some website.

```
int main(void)
{
   int answer;
   short x = 1;
   long y = 2;
   float u = 3.0;
   double v = 4.4;
   long double w = 5.54;
   char c = 'p';

   typedef enum
   {
      kAttributeInvalid,
      kBooleanAttributeActive,
      kBooleanAttributeAlarmSignal,
      kBooleanAttributeAlign64,
      kBooleanAttributeAutoNegotiationComplete,
   }codes_t;

  /* __DATE__, __TIME__, __FILE__, __LINE__ are predefined symbols */
  #if 0
  printf("Date : %s\n", __DATE__);
  printf("Time : %s\n", __TIME__);
  printf("File : %s\n", __FILE__);
  printf("Line : %d\n", __LINE__);
  #endif

  /* The size of various types */
  printf("The size of int         %zu\n", sizeof(answer));
  printf("The size of short       %zu\n", sizeof(x));
  printf("The size of long        %zu\n", sizeof(y));
  printf("The size of float       %zu\n", sizeof(u));
  printf("The size of double      %zu\n", sizeof(v));
  printf("The size of long double %zu\n", sizeof(w));
  printf("The size of char        %zu\n", sizeof(c));
  printf("The size of enum        %zu\n", sizeof(codes_t));

  return 0;
}
```

I ran this program and the output that I got is as follows.

```
The size of int         4
The size of short       2
The size of long        8
The size of float       4
The size of double      8
The size of long double 16
The size of char        1
The size of enum        4
```

I am running this on a linux PC that is running 64-bit Ubuntu.My question is if I were to run the same program on a 32-bit machine will I see different results.Or in other words does the size of the basic data types depend on

1. processor
2. Operating System
3. anything else

Comment: It quite literally depends on everything.

Comment: To me the one and only correct assumption on eg. size of int is that the size of int is always sizeof(int)

Comment: @AlW: Also sizeof(int) >= 2 as defined in ANSI C. Apart from that, all bets are off.

Comment: The size of float and double must be at least 4 and 8 respectively.  2 <= short <= int <= long.  And 1 <= char.  Otherwise all bets are off, as SecurityMatt said.

Comment: Float and double are very precise, so long as your implementation uses the IEEE standard for them. The rest just have some relative constraints, as Hot Licks noted.

Comment: why the -1 ? This question is quite reasonable.

Comment: @SecurityMatt @Hot Licks No. `char` can have more than 8 bits, so `sizeof(int) == 1` is possible, e.g. on TI 28Cxx where both have 16 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subject to having to install some libraries [probably just glibc] in it's 32-bit variant, you should be able to try this yourself by using `gcc -m32 myprog.c` [or `clang -m32 myprog.c`].

However, the only thing of your items that have been listed that will change if you move from a 64-bit x86 linux system to 32-bit x86 linux system, using gcc-based compilers, is the size of `long`. Note the heavy qualification of x86, gcc, etc - compilers have a lot of freedom. Someone could write a compiler for Linux that uses 16-bit `int` and 64-bit `long` on a 32-bit system with no huge amount of difficulty. Using that compiler to compile the Linux kernel and many of the Linux tools would probably fail [most likely including compiling `gcc` with that compiler]. But you can't really say "on this architecture" or "in this OS" or "with this compiler" ... without also qualifying what the OTHER parameters are.

Case in point: A Microsoft C/C++ compiler has a `long` that is 32 bit even on 64-bit systems. Why, I hear you ask? Because a large number of Windows API functions use `long` as a 32-bit value as legacy from when Windows was a 16-bit OS on Intel 286/386 processors. Since (some of) the system calls are backwards compatible a very long way in Windows, code that is written for 16-bit systems will still work on 64-bit Windows [unless the code is using some really unusual system calls, and of course, the STYLE will look a bit ancient]. Changing `long` to a 64-bit value would have broken some of that functioanilty, so the compiler guys at MS decided to stick with `long` = 32 bit. If you want 64-bit integers, you have to use `long long` or `int64_t` or something else, not `long`. Of course, this breaks some code that assumes that `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void *)`. Hopefully, most such code has already been fixed...

Answer (score 7):

> My question is if I were to run the same program on a 32-bit machine will I see different results

Maybe. Or maybe not.

> Or in other words does the size of the basic data types depend on 1) processor 2) Operating System 3) anything else

1. Yes, 2. yes, 3. yes, for example if you run a 32-bit app in 32-bit compatibility mode on a 64-bit OS, then it most likely will use a 32-bit word size (of course, it was compiled like that). Oh, and yes, it may depend on the compiler too.

*"And your compiler flags..."* (Thanks, Kay!)

Answer (score 4):

If you care about the exact size of the variables use

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

And then use the fixed-width types defined there:

```
uint8_t
uint16_t
uint32_t
uint64_t
```

or their signed cousins

```
int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
int64_t
```

Do not rely on the sizes of native types in C. Different compilers have different rules.

Comment: Great additional bit of info, adds clarity

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it depends on the hardware, OS, compiler and even language in some cases.

But on x86 linux, longs will be 4 bytes on 32-bit platforms, rather than 8.
The others I believe all remains the same (not sure about long double).

Anecdote:

I've worked on a 24-bit system where the word size was 24 bits, and every native type was 1 word in size. sizeof(char)? 1 (ie: 24 bits). sizeof(int)? 1 (ie: 24 bits). Etc. Fun!

Comment: IIRC, `long double` used to be 96 bits on x86-32.

Comment: @PQuinn, did that implementation have stdio.h?

Answer (score 2):

The sizes are set in stone by the compiler at compile-time, because the compiler has to emit size-specific instructions, lay out the members in structs, and know struct sizes for all required address calculations.

So if you compile your source into a 64-bit binary and run it on a bunch of different systems, the types will have the same sizes on each run, if the system supports the binary at all.

If you then compile the source into a 32-bit binary or use different compiler switches, when you run that on a bunch of different systems then the numbers may be different from the 64-bit case, but they will be consistent over all the different systems.

Comment: I like this answer, because it clearly states that the sizes are decided by the compiler. I could implement a translator (compiler or interpreter) that uses 111-bit char, short, int, long, etc ..., and regardless of 32-vs-64-bit the size of those types would all be 1.